# Find the $x$ at which the local maxima of a function ocours.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, definite-integrals

> The function $f(x) = \int\limits_{-1}^{x}t(e^t-1)(t-1)(t-2)^3(t-3)^5 dt$ has a local maxima at $x=?$

First, I differentiated $f(x)$ and found its roots.

That came out to be $x = 0,1,2,3$. Now, one of those numbers, when plugged into $f(x)$, must give the largest value compared to the others.

In our case, since we are integrating, we would need to find the $x$ that minimizes the negative area of the function that we are integrating.

By further work and analyzing the function, I figured out that the answer must be $0$ or $2.$

But, I don't know what to do next?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually plug in the values and compare..

Comment: where do i plug the values in? Do we have f(x) just in x to "plug and compare"?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The sign of $$f^{'}(x)=x(e^x-1)(x-1)(x-2)^3(x-3)^5$$  is $-,+,-,+$ respectively on the intervals $(-1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,\infty).$ From this you can finish without further calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You differentiated and found the roots correctly:
$$f^{'}(x)=x(e^x-1)(x-1)(x-2)^3(x-3)^5=0 \Rightarrow \\
x_0=\{0,1,2,3\};$$
**Method 1.** Check the neighborhood of the critical points:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
x_0&f'(x_0-\epsilon)&f'(x_0+\epsilon)&\text{Type of stationary point}\\
\hline
0&-&-&\text{inflection}\\
1&-&+&\text{local minimum}\\
2&+&-&\text{local maximum}\\
3&-&+&\text{local minimum}\\
\end{array}$$

**Method 2.** Check the second (or higher) order derivative at the critical points:
$$\begin{align}f''(0)&=0 \ \ \ \text{(inconclusive)}\\
f''(1)&=32(e-1)>0 \ \ \text{(local minimum)}\\
f''(2)&=0 \ \ \text{(inconclusive)}\\
f''(3)&=0 \ \ \text{(inconclusive)}\\
\end{align}$$
Now you can use [higher order derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test):
$$\begin{align}f'''(0)&<0 \ \ \text{(strictly decreasing inflection point)}\\
f'''(2)&=0, f^{(4)}(2)<0 \ \ \text{(local maximum)}\\
f'''(3)&=f^{(4)}(3)=f^{(5)}(3)=0, f^{(6)}(3)>0 \ \ \text{(local minimum)}.\end{align}$$
Note: You don't have to calculate the higher order derivatives completely, but you should focus on the corresponding factor and the resulting sign.

Comment: +1 for displaying the behavior of $f'$ via nice table.

Comment: Thank you and Happy New 2019!

Comment: So, Is the answer 2?

Comment: Yes, $f(2)\approx -6965.2$ is the local maximum. See [WolframAlpha answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(from+-1+to+x)+t(e%5Et-1)(t-1)(t-2)%5E3(t-3)%5E5+dt+where+x%3D0,1,2,3+approximate) (click on approximate form).